# How to shrink virtuoso.db file size after deleting a large graph?

Tags: virtuoso, openlink-virtuoso

I deleted a large graph in the conductor of a Virtuoso SPARQL 7.20.3217 endpoint but the size of `virtuoso.db` is still 3.6 GB as it was before, even after restarting the server. Is there a command to clean the database and delete leftover parts like cache and indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed, deleting data from the DB does not immediately free the disk space previously occupied by that data. Virtuoso has an [auto-compaction feature](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/dbadm/#indexdefragm) which will eventually free space. New data will be loaded into the space previously occupied by deleted data, but of course this reuse will be imperfect. You may be able to free some space by running a [`CHECKPOINT;`](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/checkpoint/) or the [`DB..VACUUM ();` procedure](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/fn_vacuum/). You can also do a [backup-dump-and-reload](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/backup_recovery/#dbrebuild) to immediately reclaim disk – though you must temporarily consume substantially more disk space during this process. Indexes can also be dropped and rebuilt, but this does not generally free up very much disk, in itself.

Comment: `DB.VACUUM();` actually increased the size to 4.7 GB and running a checkpoint didn't change the size. I will try the backup dump and reload next.

Comment: The backup-dump-and-reload did the trick, thanks!